# Pycharm unresolved references not shown despite being active

Tags: linux, pycharm

My pycharm version does not mark unresolved references.
In this screenshot, I want to use `os.path.join("a","b")` **without** loading the module and pycharm doesn't mark it as expected

[image]

As [suggested on pycharm's web page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/resolving-references.html) I should activate the corresponding Python Inspection:
`File | Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections - Python - Unresolved references` -
but this is already active in my case:

[image]

I'm running `PyCharm 2022.1.2 (Professional Edition)` on `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS`

**EDIT:**
As mentioned in the comments, this seems to be a bug. For anyone having the same problem, here is the bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-54842/Pycharm-unresolved-references-not-shown-despite-being-active

Comment: Strange. Do you have a project environment set? Is PyCharm still loading the symbols (it is slow at start)? Or your code defines os (somewhere)? [where you go, if you Control-Click the word "os"?]

Comment: What exactly do you mean with environment? I have a remote python interpreter, if you mean that? I can also give more information on that if you'd let me know what you'd like to see.
In the 'Notifications' it says that indexing is completed (I also did `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restarted pycharm to restart indexing).
If I hit F4 (Should be ctrl + click) on "os" I don't go anywhere, so it really doesn't seem to be able to resolve the `os` module, right?

Comment: Do you have a project interpreter? Settings/Properties -> Project: XXX -> Interpreter. Without knowing an interpreter, PyCharm cannot interfere pretty nothing. Are you using Python 2, Python 3 or maybe a Python 4000 which include os.path. In the next line, if you write `spam_spam_spam += foo_bar(3)`, do you get some warning?

Comment: Yes, I do have a project interpreter. It's a "Remote Python 3.6.9" interpreter.
I do get a warning if I write `spam_spam_spam += foo_bar(3)` in the next line. `spam_spam_spam` is highlighted and it says "Name 'spam_spam_spam' can be undefined". However, `foo_bar` is not highlighted in any way.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it is a bug of PyCharm. On my case, I get an error. But if i disable the option you indicated, the error disappears. But the setting is about being a warning, not an error. So there should be an overriding setting (or bug) somewhere. But so I would fill a bug. (either a true bug, or a usability/interface bug)

Comment: Yeah, I remember it was working before and I think (although I'm not sure) this issue appeared after an update of PyCharm.